# Selenium + Java, finding the correct element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```html
<button class="positive auth-button" tabindex="2" type="submit"> Send Me a Push </button>
```

The above is my HTML code.

Code I've tried to find the element:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[type='submit'][class='positive auth-button']")).click();
```

and

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("button[@type='submit'][class='positive auth-button")).click();
```

Comment: Which element do you want to locate?

Comment: Post the code you tried and tell us what was the problem with it.

Comment: this is what i have tried: driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[type='submit'][class='positive auth-button']")).click();

Comment: this as well:  driver.findElement(By.xpath("button[@type='submit'][class='positive auth-button")).click();

Comment: '<div class="row-label push-label">
<input type="hidden" name="factor" value="Duo Push">
<span class="label factor-label">
<i class="icon-smartphone-check"></i>
Duo Push


<small class="recommended">
Recommended
</small>


</span>
<button class="positive auth-button" tabindex="2" type="submit"> Send Me a Push </button>
</div>
'

Comment: <div class="row-label push-label"> is in iframe or not ?

Comment: and error trace please ?

Comment: @Shams, try to implement [ExplicitWait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits)

Comment: yes its in a frame, but that i have already identified for previous testing. its in that same frame. i use the switch to frame code and clicking on a logo for previous test that works. currently now my test takes me to the frame but it wont locate that "send me a push"

Comment: Are you sure when you are trying to identified "send me a push" button, your wedDriver has focus on it.

Comment: You can try some sys-outs statments before/after switching to iframe

Comment: another snippet of code, after the frame work to the "button", html> <form action="/frame/prompt" method="post" id="login-form" class="inline">

Comment: @Shams If you are correctly switching to the desired frame what is the error you see on `tried to find the element`?

Comment: IDK about what do you mean by previous testing ? But If you had switched to iframe earlier in your code and then switched back to main content and again you wanna click a button inside an iframe , you must switch again , it's as simple as that !

Comment: this is my code to switch to the frame> driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("duo_iframe")));

Comment: i used the that code to switch to the frame, it locates the frame then i used > driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[type='submit'][class='positive auth-button']")).click(); , at this point the error is: unable to find element

Comment: @cruisepandey thank you i resolved the issue

Comment: @Shams : Great man !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code for that:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); 
WebElement button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector(".positive.auth-button[type='submit']")));
button.click();
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".positive.auth-button[type='submit']"}
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)

Comment: @Shams, post a link to the page.

Comment: @Andersson, not the same, but similar. I have posted my answer before I got info from OP.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code:

```
    WebElement ele1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='positive auth-button'][@type='submit']"));
    JavascriptExecutor clickbtn = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    clickbtn.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele1);
```

Also,you can go with following code

```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 2000).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='positive auth-button'][@type='submit']")));
```

Comment: tried the above elements not found, let me check if there is a another hidden form, it looks to me like this is a form in a frame work which i have already identified.

Comment: If element is located in iframes then first you have to switch to iframe using driver.switchTo().frame(0);

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
```

WebElement button = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector(".positive.auth-button[type='submit']")));
button.click();